# Scala bufferedIterator incrementing head in inner function

Tags: scala

Hi I'm seeing what I believe is odd behaviour in scala. Calling head on a bufferedIterator seems to be incrementing the head in a inner function. Either my expetations are wrong in which case why is the output correct. Or is the output wrong?

**given:**

```
import scala.io.Source

val source = Source.fromString("abcdef")

val buff1 = source.buffered;

println("outer head 1: " +buff1.head)
println("outer head 2: " +buff1.head)

def readLine():List[String] = {
  def buffered = source.buffered
  def readLine(tokens:List[String] , partialToken:String):List[String] = {
    println("head1 " + buffered.head)
    println("head2 " + buffered.head)
    return Nil;
  }
  return (readLine(Nil, ""));
}

readLine();
```

The expected output of this to me is

```
outer head 1: a
outer head 2: a
head1: a
head2: a
```

actual output is as follows.

```
outer head 1: a
outer head 2: a
head1 b
head2 c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scala.io.Source` is and behaves like an `Iterator[Char]`. So you must make sure not to use it in several places at once: `Iterator.next` is called 3 times from 3 different `BufferedSource` in your example, hence the different values you get out of it:

1. `buff1.head`:  the buffered source has not buffered anything yet, so asking for `head` here calls `next` on the inner source, hence the first `a`.
2. `buff1.head` again: here the head has already been buffered, so you get `a` and the inner source isn't changed.
3. `buffered.head`: since `buffered` is a `def`, this is equivalent to `source.buffered.head`. This new buffered source has not buffered anything yet, so asking for `head` retrieves an element from the inner source, hence the `b`.
4. `buffered.head`: this creates yet another buffered source, same as above, and you get `c`.

The bottom line is: **if you call `source.buffered`, never use `source` again directly, and do not call it several times either**.

Your example can be fixed by calling `buffered` immediately:

```
val source = Source.fromString("abcdef").buffered
```

You could also turn `def buffered =` into `val buffered =` to make sure `source.buffered` is not called several times.

Comment: Because of that I was able to finish this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27206/first-scala-program-csv-parsing-does-it-stick-to-conventions thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Calling head on a bufferedIterator seems to be incrementing the head in a inner function.

Note: (July 2016 3 years later)

[Commit 11688eb](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/11688eb95b88f02c89c5974c3ce22290b57a5374) shows:

> ### SI-9691 `BufferedIterator` should expose a `headOption`
>
> This exposes a new API to the `BufferedIterator` trait.
>   It will return the next element of an iterator as an `Option`.
>
> The return will be  `Some(value)` if there is a next value, and `None` if there is not a next element.

That should help avoid any kind of increment.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, except it increments not a function, but a simple field : [IndexedSeqLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqLike.scala#L66) on line 66, you can check it out by yourself using some IDE debbuger and following execution step by step